# Scale image to fit tile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Let me start with my code:

```
UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TileMap.gif"];
[tempImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, tileSize, tileSize)];


mapLabels[w][h] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cursor.x, cursor.y, tileSize, tileSize)];
mapLabels[w][h].text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", map[w][h]];
mapLabels[w][h].backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: tempImage];
mapLabels[w][h].textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;


[self.view addSubview:mapLabels[w][h]];
```

I made a map of tiles out of `UILabels`. I wanted to put an `Image` on the labels so I used the `colorWithPatternImage`. It works but my tile pictures are very high resolution and my `UILabel` tiles can be any size so I need the image to be the same size. What I am currently trying to do to scale it with the `drawInRect` is not working, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

There is a scale property for UIImages. You could try something like:

```
tempImage.scale = mapLabels[w][h].tileSize.x / tempImage.tileSize.x
```